# How to refer to Excel columns without headers in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, excel, adodb, vba

I dived into documentation but since I didn't find any information (Well, actually I found similarities with some other SO questions but not what I want), I'm asking you guys to help me :

I'm executing a tsql query over an ADODB connection, to retrieve data from an Excel File (*.xlsx) into another one.
This file is composed as follow :

```
 Header1     Header2     Header3
---------   ---------   ---------
    A1          B1          C1
    A2          B2          C2
    A3          B3          C3
   ....        ....        ....
```

I want to retrieve the headers too so here's a part of the whole program, containing the connection string

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

With con
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=path\file.xlsx; _
         Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"""
    Set rs = .Execute("Select * From [Sheet1$]")
    .Close
End With
```

Here I retrieve all the columns, but what if I want column B, then column A, then column C, e.g. something like that :

```
Set rs = .Execute("Select colb, cola, colc From [Sheet1$]")
```

The problem there is that I don't know the terms which should replace colb, cola, colc since I can't use the headers of the columns

Regards

PS : I don't know much about these technologies, so I may be wrong with the terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not my answer, but from a colleague who sits next to me ;)

```
Set rs = .Execute("SELECT F2, F1, F3 FROM [Sheet1$]")
```

(not tested)

Comment: It works almost perfectly but that's enough, thank your colleague for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to read the columns as they are in the file:

```
Set rs = .Execute("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]")
```

and later map them to the required variables? I mean - what do you do with `rs` later in your code?

Comment: Yes, i already did it and it works, but I wanted some optimization here :)